# Jenkins reports reverse proxy setup incorrect with Apache using virtual hosts with SNI

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, jenkins, sni

I'm setting up a Jenkins server, to run under Tomcat behind Apache. I'm using virtual hosts with SSL using SNI so I can access it at https://jenkins.example.com, and serve something else on, say, http://www.example.com.

I've got it up and running, but when I click "Manage Jenkins", it tells me [It appears your reverse proxy setup is broken](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+says+my+reverse+proxy+setup+is+broken).

Note that I'm using a self-signed SSL certificate, and jenkins.example.com is not the default virtual hosts.

The relevant apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName jenkins.example.com
        Redirect / https://jenkins.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName jenkins.example.com

  SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/jenkins.example.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/jenkins.example.com.key

  <Location />
     AuthType Digest
     AuthName "Jenkins"
     AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswords"
     Require valid-user
   </Location>

   ProxyRequests     Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Proxy http://localhost:8080*>
     Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse  /  https://jenkins.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

If I do:

```
curl --user "username:password" --digest -k https://jenkins.example.com/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test -L
```

Then I see the output:

```
<div/>
```

If I run wget with debug, then I see at that some point wget gets a pointer to http instead of https, not sure why that's happening or if it's related, but it does redirect properly:

```
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2012 19:47:16 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://jenkins.example.com/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test-for-reverse-proxy-setup
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 11.04, Apache 2.2.17, Tomcat 6.0.28, Jenkins 1.448.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one issue that I see with your config is that:

```
ProxyPassReverse  /  https://jenkins.example.com
```

Should be:

```
ProxyPassReverse  /  https://jenkins.example.com/
```

---

Seems like the service is sending `http://` instead of `https://` location headers (probably because your connection to its listener from Apache is unencrypted on the localhost listener), in which case you'll need to add:

```
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://jenkins.example.com/
```

---

So, what's probably occurring currently is the API call is failing because it gets an `http://` address in the `Location:` header of the redirect (which is missed for un-translation in the `ProxyPassReverse` because it's not `http`).

It sends the request to that location and gets *another* redirect response, from your `<VirtualHost *:80>`.  Their validity checker knows that ain't right and errors, while `curl` follows one more redirect and gets a valid response.

Add the `ProxyPassReverse` for `http://` above and this should correct the issue, if I'm right.

Comment: Even after following all these suggestions, I still got the *It appears your reverse proxy setup is broken* message. The final step that was missing was adding to the `<VirtualHost *:80>` part a `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"` ... and to the `<VirtualHost *:443>` part a `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"`. Now, finally, the *broken* message is gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache as reverse proxy, it needs to be at least 2.2.18 and set the option `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` (earlier versions only have values On and Off, both of which are wrong); as well as `nocanon` in the `ProxyPass` directive.

Both need to be set within the VirtualHost, as AllowEncodedSlashes isn't inherited.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        ServerName build.example.org
        ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
        ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyRequests     Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179008/923560:

Make sure the Jenkins URL configured in the System Configuration matches the URL you're using to access Jenkins.

To reach the System Configuration:

1. Go to your Jenkins page
2. Click Manage Jenkins
3. Click Configure System
4. Scroll to **Jenkins Location** and find Jenkins URL.

Ensure that port value matches with the port value set in the `<arguments>` section of the **jenkins.xml** file located in the Jenkins folder on your machine.