# Apache reverse proxy config with SSL for Jenkins and Sonar

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-2.4, jenkins

I am running two services behind an Apache server: Jenkins (Port 8080) and SonarQube (Port 9000).

My apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server
  Redirect permanent / https://server.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server.domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://server.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName server.domain.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key

  ProxyPass        /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins
  ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://server.domain.com/jenkins
  ProxyPassReverse /jenkins https://server.domain.com/jenkins

  ProxyPass        /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse /sonar http://localhost:9000/sonar

  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except that Jenkins is complaining with this message: **It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.**

When I run the **ReverseProxySetupMonitor** test provided by Jenkins, the error message indicates that something with the reverse proxy is not set up correctly, as is does not replace http with https:

```
$ curl -iLk -e https://server.domain.com/jenkins/manage https://server.domain.com/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test
[...]
404 http://server.domain.com/jenkins/manage vs. https://server.domain.com/jenkins/manage
[...]
```

This only appeared **after** I enabled SSL on the server (which is now using a self-signed certificate).

**Question:**
How do I fix the reverse proxy setup so that Jenkins is happy? Bonus points for tips on how to improve the apache config file.

I already checked the following two related questions:

- [Apache as a proxy for Nexus, Jenkins and Foreman (Several VirtualHosts on same domain, IP and Port)](https://serverfault.com/questions/525861/apache-as-a-proxy-for-nexus-jenkins-and-foreman-several-virtualhosts-on-same-d)
- [Jenkins reports reverse proxy setup incorrect with Apache using virtual hosts with SNI](https://serverfault.com/questions/350780/jenkins-reports-reverse-proxy-setup-incorrect-with-apache-using-virtual-hosts-wi)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache) on wiki Jenkins mentioned that as **per July 2014**, the recommended configuration for Jenkins reverse proxy. The missing parameter is `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"` and `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"`

So the configuration became

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@localhost
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://www.example.com/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly! I also had to do `sudo a2enmod headers`, otherwise I would get `Invalid command 'RequestHeader'`

Comment: Can you explain why are you using two `ProxyPassReverse` directives for the same path (`/`) ?

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Apache Front-end setup for Jenkins**

The main differences here are:

- How to set up a temporary certificate
- stopping apache winging about not having any ssl cache

My setup:

- Install was to d:\ (not c:\ - adapt this to your needs)
- Jenkins is on port 8080
- Unzip Apache httpd-2.4.18-win64-VC14.zip (from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) to d:\ .
- Install OpenSSL Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2f.exe (http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) to d:\OpenSSL-Win64
- Create the ssl certificate:

  - cd to the OpenSSL bin directory and run the magic:

    ```
     pushd d:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
     set OPENSSL_CONF=openssl.cfg
     openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt
    ```
- Copy the server.* files from d:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin to D:\Apache24\conf
- Edit d:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf :

  - Search and replace "c:/" with "d:/"
  - Change after the line "Listen 80", adding "Listen 443":

    ```
    Listen 80
    Listen 443
    ```
  - Uncomment these lines:

    ```
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    ```
  - Update "#ServerName www.example.com:80" to:

    ```
    ServerName myserver.mydomain:80
    ```
  - Add this at the end:

    ```
    <IfModule socache_shmcb_module>
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
    </IfModule>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName myserver
      Redirect permanent / https://myserver.mydomain/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName myserver.mydomain
      Redirect permanent / https://myserver.mydomain/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile conf/server.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/server.key
                ServerAdmin  me@mydomain
                ProxyRequests             Off
                ProxyPreserveHost On
                AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
                <Proxy *>
                            Order deny,allow
                            Allow from all
                </Proxy>
                ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
                ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
                ProxyPassReverse  /  http://myserver.mydomain/
                RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
                RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    </VirtualHost>
    ```

I did not stop Jenkins listening on port 8080, so I can still connect if apache fails. My objective in using https is to hide parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Docker container to run Apache2 as a reverse proxy for Sonarqube at the same host.

Follow the Source Code.
https://github.com/clebermasters/sonarqube-https-apache2